# Why is there a PATH_SEPARATOR constant?

Tags: php

Isn't this `/`  ?

Why is there a constant for it? It's not like it can change, right?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`PATH_SEPARATOR` is the character used to separate many paths in a unique string (like `include_path` in php.ini).

Its value is `':'` on a UNIX system and `';'` on a Windows system.

What you're talking about (`'/'` on UNIX and `'\'` on Windows) is the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant.

Answer (score 13):

As your original question states: "Why is there a PATH_SEPARATOR constant?", windows uses a semi-colon `;`, while other systems use a colon `:`

However I think you've mistaken PATH_SEPARATOR with DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR

PATH_SEPARATOR delimits multiple paths in the same string. For example when used in windows environment variables.

c:\path\to\a`;`c:\path\to\b

DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR separates the directories within the path:
In Windows

```
\
```

In other systems

```
/
```

As mentioned by others, windows also accepts `/`

Comment: Open up a command console and try `cd /valid/path/` in windows. I think you'll find that this works

Comment: Try `cd /`, and you'll see that it doesn't.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, I just did on 3 windows 7 machines. Worked without any problems.

Comment: what's the point of trying *three* machines with the *same* version? Try a different version...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Windows does support a mixture of forward slashes and backslashes, at the API level.

See, for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

"lpFileName [in]: The name of the file or device to be created or opened. You may use either forward slashes (/) or backslashes (\\) in this name."

Comment: That's exactly the problem - it supports it at the API level. Try `system("dir /mydirectory")` - it will complain, because it thinks that's a parameter to the `dir` command. So although PHP supports `/`, you can easily end up with weird problems because you assumed it's going to work *everywhere*. I just wanted to point out this.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>It can. It is `\` in Windows and `/` in Linux (and prettymuch everywhere else), although modern versions of Windows do accept `/` as a separator.</strike>

Ooops this is about the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant.

`PATH_SEPARATOR` is indeed the constant to separate various paths as seen in [PéCés answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9769090/511529).