# Xampp - can't read PHP, MySQLi at the browser - Fatal error with PEAR

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp, pear

I don't know what exactly happens because I have a page ready to handle-up a login system but it's only programmed in html and css yet. Why?

Because when I try to program something in php like this to start making the login system works;

Document called Connections

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "84df86a16c3bf8fb94dd3824b9144604", "thunderorbit");
?>
```

My register document with all the html

```
<?php
require '/ThunderOrbit/Loginscreen/Connections.php';
?>
```

all the html (I won't paste it or it will ocupy the whole page xD but it works before I write nothing in PHP or using mySQLi with PHP)

**The error log;**

```
Warning: require(/ThunderOrbit/Loginscreen/Connections.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ThunderOrbit\Loginscreen\Loginscreen-Index.php on line 4

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/ThunderOrbit/Loginscreen/Connections.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\ThunderOrbit\Loginscreen\Loginscreen-Index.php on line 4
```

Attention to **(include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')** please I don't understand what to do, help!!

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was here:

*Change*

```
<?php

require '/ThunderOrbit/Loginscreen/Loginscreen-Connections/Loginscreen-Connections.php';

?>
```

*To*

```
<?php

require '/Loginscreen-Connections/Loginscreen-Connections.php';

?>
```

Because PHP isn't the same as HTML or CSS, regarding links.

Comment: There is a troubleshooting checklist, to help find the cause of the problem in this kind of cases here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory/36577021#36577021

Answer (score 0):

Maybe PHP Windows and Linux compatibility path, change `\` to `PATH_SEPARATOR` or `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constants.
[Reference about PATH_SEPARATOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769052/why-is-there-a-path-separator-constant)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure PHP has access to that file.

Answer (score 0):

If the file you are requiring is in the same directory just name the file.

```
require('Connections.php');
```